# How can I forward (redirect) a call programmatically on Android?

Tags: android

How can I programmatically redirect an incoming call to a specific number on Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is "you can't". Call forwarding is the responsibility of your phone carrier and nothing to do with Android. By the time a call has reached your phone, it is too late to forward it anywhere.

Further to this, if you could programmatically redirect calls (by somehow using code to tell your carrier that you want a redirection enabled), this could be open to abuse by malicious apps.

In other words, if it were possible, I could write an app to secretly and invisibly redirect all of your calls to a phone that I owned thus intercepting all of your business/private calls.