# How can I redirect a call after 3 second?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to call an exact number for just 3 sec and then the call should end and automatically redial to another fixed number.. how is this possible? anyone please help me....I already try it using phone state listener but its not working.`case

```
    {
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d("CallRecorder", "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK starting recording");
            if (!incomingNumber.equals("+919037117434")||!incomingNumber.equals("9037117434")) {
                try {
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass()
                            .getName());
                    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method
                            .invoke(telephonyManager);
                    telephonyService.endCall();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("", e.getMessage());
                }
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "9037117434"));
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
```

Comment: add a `Thread.sleep(3000);` after starting the call, then whenever the sleep is dont terminate the call, I didnt try it but theoretically it should work. please give me a feedback

Answer (score 0):

The method you used to redirect a call will not work, kindly check the link [How can I forward (redirect) a call programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458933/how-can-i-forward-redirect-a-call-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: actualy I want to call an exact number for just 3 sec and then the call should end and automatically redial to another fixed number

Comment: yes, i understand your requirement so you can Thread.sleep(3000) for delay. But the question is can receive a intent in your receiver during a incoming call? And only redial is not working?